# System ui change

Tags: java, android, xml, operating-system

Is there any way to add another button beside copy when a text gets selected in android?

It could work like a service and triggered after app installation. When a text is selected it should appear and add a new button besides copy button.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggePF.png)

[see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggePF.png)

Comment: This is probably possible. What research have you done on your own for this?

Comment: I have searched on google but I found nothing. I am confused about where to start. Any similar tutorial will also be helpful.

Comment: It's impossible in native Android OS.

Comment: It's possible though https://medium.com/google-developers/custom-text-selection-actions-with-action-process-text-191f792d2999